# Save an image (PNG) with annotations as a PDF

Tags: macos, pdf, preview

Is it possible to save an image that was annotated in Preview as a PDF file so I can edit it again later, even after restarting Preview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use File > "Export as PDF…" or even File > Print… > click PDF options in lower-left corner as a way to convert anything open in Preview to PDF. However, any annotations made to an image format such as PNG without converting will be flattened/rasterized when saved or converted to PDF and can't be edited. You will need to first convert the image to PDF  **then** annotate in order to be able to edit annotations later.